Present a laptop as a keyboard via usb-c to a raspberry pi
I have a laptop (dual boot linux/windows, if this could help, and with both usb-a and -c ports).
I also have a raspberry pi 5 (I just received this starter pack for my 42th birthday).
I don't have a spare keyboard (basically the last desktop pc I used was 15+ years ago and I'm pretty sure it used a ps/2 connector).
I might buy one (I can found one for 10€) but I was wondering if I can connect the pi to my pc and tell it that it's just a keyboard.
Do I need a specific usb cable? is there any driver I can/must use on the laptop side?

for the monitor I may use my old tv, and I agree that in any case they are cheap. My only thing is that I don't really have space (basically just a side of a desk) and I would have liked to save that

connect remotely ... research Raspberry Pi headless

"Present a laptop as a keyboard via usb-c to a raspberry pi" - That would require the laptop/PC to act as a USB gadget. But PCs typically always have the role of USB host and have USB host controller(s), and rarely (if ever) have a USB device controller. Instead consider using a USB connection as a serial link using CDC ACM protocol; the laptop would be a terminal and the RPi runs headless (w/o a video display).




"Present a laptop as a keyboard via usb-c to a raspberry pi" - That would require the laptop/PC to act as a USB gadget.



yeah, that's the goal



But PCs typically always have the role of USB host and have USB host controller(s),



yeah, I understand it



and rarely (if ever) have a USB device controller.



so, this means it's an hardware problem? how do I know if my laptop have it? Assuming it doesn't, is there a way to emulate it via software?

https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/tutorials/2023/how-to-connect-to-a-headless-raspberry-pi-using-serial

If it is "headfully" connected to a monitor / TV and has an X server running, you can set up x11vnc (or a Wayland equivalent if you are using a Wayland compositor instead, assuming one exists) and control it over your home network. (But then you'll need to set up the x11vnc server over SSH or serial first.)

This requires a lot of effort, as it greatly misunderstands how USB connections work. It is probably best to just accept the PC only has "Host" USB ports, and not "Slave" USB ports.
However, if you really wanted to do it, it is possible. It does require hardware though, so again it's probably not worth it in this case. Here's the link: https://euer.krebsco.de/a-software-kvm-switch.html

I was looking for the same.
Could find the cable, made the app myself.
You can check it out on GitHub
https://github.com/sipper69/Control3

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
